# Linked List program error? In C

Tags: c, linked-list

Trying to study linked list and tried my program on gcc 4.1.2 on terminal and Xcode.

xcode Error: Thread 1: Exe_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1)
Terminal Error; Segmentation fault

and i have no clue what the xcode error is. for some reason it gives me that same error for some programs that work on other gcc?

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node *link;
struct node {int item; link next;};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  int i;
  link t = malloc(sizeof *t);
  while ( t != NULL)
    {
      for ( i = 0; i < 10;i++)
        {
          t->item = i;
          t = t->next;
        }
    }
  int count = 0;
  while ( t != NULL)
    {
      for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
          if (count ==  3)
            {
              printf("%d\n", t->item);
              continue;
            }
          t = t->next;
          count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `malloc` gives you an uninitialised chunk of memory. `t = t->next` will very likely produce an illegal pointer. You also allocate memory for one node and then try to make a linked list of ten nodes from it. You must allocate memory for each node when you create it. Also, if you continue the loop when you print the third node, you'll never advance the node nor increase the count. Did you mean ´break`? Finally, what nas been `malloc`ed must be `free`d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dereferenced `t->next`, which is allocated via `malloc()` and not assigned some value, and invoked *undefined behavior*. You have to allocate buffer for second node and later.

Also you should get the pointer `t` back before dealing with the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node *link;
struct node {int item; link next;};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  int i;
  link t = malloc(sizeof *t);
  link head = t; /* add this line to get the pointer back */
  while ( t != NULL)
    {
      for ( i = 0; i < 10;i++)
        {
          t->item = i;
          t->next = malloc(sizeof *t); /* add this line */
          t = t->next;
        }
    }
  int count = 0;
  t = head; /* add this line to get the pointer back */
  while ( t != NULL) /* convinated with inner loop, this will lead to infinite loop */
    {
      for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++) /* you may want to check if t != NULL here for safety */
        {
          /* not invalid but odd program that print the 4th element again and again */
          if (count ==  3)
            {
              printf("%d\n", t->item);
              continue;
            }
          t = t->next;
          count++;
        }
    }
}
```